# Disable VM Autostart - XenServer

Tags: virtual-machines, high-availability, xenserver, start, xencenter

After running updates in **XenServer 6.5** I noticed that some virtual machines that were recently **turned off** started turning on again **automatically** after the **server I applied updates to restarted**.

When I go to apply updates through **xen center** I get the following notification and have to **disable** before I can proceed:
[image]

I'd like to disable this altogether. I've also **disabled high availability** temporarily hoping this would do the trick but it has not.

Any suggestions/assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Re-enable HA put off the autostart on the VM, and disable HA after. HA is off at one of my customer, and HA still pop'ed two VM up last shutdown, so I remarked that the setting was still on/active somehow on the host. If it fix your issue let me know, will write as an answer

Comment: How do I tell which VM's have autostart enabled on them? I've looked at the properties for each VM but I cannot find anything for the autostart feature?

Comment: Will post as an answer, as I will show you on a printscreen

Answer (score 0):

Re-enable HA put off the autostart on the VM, and disable HA after. HA is off at one of my customer, and HA still pop'ed two VM up last shutdown, so I remarked that the setting was still on/active somehow on the host.

To show where it's please see the below picture, HA is **off** but the restart policy is at **on**. That VM will restart if the host will shutdown, but will not move as the heartbeat is not active. As you can see I can't change the setting as HA is off.

[image]

Comment: When I select the properties for my VM's after enabling HA I do not have a 'High Availability' option listed like you have in your picture. All I  have is a 'Start Options' option where I can select the start order, an 'attempt to start next VM after x seconds option, HA restart priority where I can select to either restart, restart if possible, or do not restart. I confirmed and HA is enabled for my resource pool.

Comment: @jrd1989 my version is older, check your pool setting then ! like show there on that pic; http://sajjan.com.np/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/HA-status.png and click configure ha

Comment: @jrd1989 if nothing work, you can do http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX133910 in the cli, as the gui can be bugged anyhow

Comment: My pool has the same information displayed as yours in the picture you provided. As mentioned, I've disabled HA from here in the past but VM's still reboot automatically. Maybe if I set them all to not restart and then disable HA it will work. I will disable HA and try running the CLI command you provided.

Comment: @jrd1989 Yes, sorry, iam not native english, but yes it's what I meant, to change the value while HA is on, to remove the HA after.

Comment: I changed all of the VM's to 'do not restart' and disabled HA. The next time I reboot a server for patching I will watch out to see if any of the VM's that are turned off automatically start up. Thank you for the suggestions and help.